# Reading multiple json files and getting the counts group by specific columns in Python

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I have multiple JSON files like json1 , json2 , json3 etc comes periodically.Format of each json file is somewhat like below with StartTime mentioned for each row

```
   {
   "SQLS": 
   [
   {
      "ID": "0001",
      "SQLText": "INSERT INTO tech as Select * from employee where emp department = 
     'tech'",
      "Properties": {
       "Type": "Static",
       "Source": "GP",
       "db": "emp_db",
        "StartTime": "2022-11-16 20:24:45.979057",
       "loginID": "Mike",
       "QueryID": "q101"
      },
     "ID": "0002",
      "SQLText": "INSERT INTO sales as Select * from employee where emp department = 
    'sales'",
     "Properties": {
        "Type": "Static",
        "Source": "sybase",
        "db": "emp_db",
      "StartTime": "2022-11-16 20:24:45.979057",
      "loginID": "Mike",
        "QueryID": "q102"
      },

     "ID": "0003",
      "SQLText": "INSERT INTO emp as Select * from employee where emp department = 
    'accounts'",
      "Properties": {
        "Type": "Static",
        "Source": "postgres",
        "db": "emp_db",
         "StartTime": "2022-11-17 20:24:45.979057",
       "loginID": "Gerath",
        "QueryID": "q103"
      },
   "ID": "0006",
      "SQLText": "INSERT INTO tech as Select * from employee where emp department = 
    'tech'",
      "Properties": {
        "Type": "Static",
        "Source": "postgres",
        "db": "victor_db",
         "StartTime": "2022-11-16 20:24:45.979057",
         "loginID": "Tracie",
        "QueryID": "q103"
      },
"ID": "0009",
      "SQLText": "INSERT INTO emp as Select * from employee where emp department = 
    'accounts'",
      "Properties": {
        "Type": "Static",
        "Source": "postgres",
        "db": "sales_db",
         "StartTime": "2022-11-18 20:24:45.979057",
        "loginID": "Naggy",
        "QueryID": "q103"
      },
    "ID": "0004",
      "SQLText": "INSERT INTO tech as Select * from employee where emp department = 
   'tech'",
     "Properties": {
        "Type": "Static",
        "Source": "GP",
        "db": "emp_db",
        "StartTime": "2022-11-17 20:24:45.979057",
        "loginID": "Gracie",
        "QueryID": "q104"
      }
    }
             ]
              }
```

My requirement is to read each file and get counts group by db,loginId and date. Result set to be stored in respective datefile as csv , So if the json file has date for 3 dates like here 2022-11-16, 2022-11-17, 2022-11-18 (From startTime) the counts will go to three date files. The method will itself create the files as per the date in startTime

**2022-11-16.csv
2022-11-17.csv
2022-11-18.csv**

Each file will have data for respective date in below format

**Cat 2022-11-16.csv**

```
Database   ,LoginId , count(*)
Emp_db ,Mike, 2
victor_db, Tracie,1
```

Kindly suggest if there is better solution to it.

Thanks

Comment: JSON is a structured format where objected are nested where as dataframes are flat tabular format. It will be much easier to use some JSON lib to process the data. If you insist on using pandas, then you need to pre-process JSON files to bring all elements in format as mentioned by "orient" element in this [read_json](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html)

Comment: Thanks Azhar for suggestion, I have changed my title a bit. But I thought this will best done in dataframes as I need csv file  with he counts towards the end. Also I can reorder the nested structure in the pre process.

Comment: As a trial, you can create a sample JSON file with couple of JSON elements from your data and try importing it with pandas.read_json() to get an idea if your data format is supported or what changes you need to support it.

Comment: I actually tried to read it in dataframe and even got the counts but i am facing a  challenge for  producing multiple csv date files on fly per the Json date condition

Comment: Please post the source code you have tried so far.

Comment: Difficult to put source code here from official network.  I am normalizing the columns in dataframe first and getting  the desired counts for the two fields. The challenge is to to group by date which is to be extracted from startTime filed of json